# How to describe "touch" in NetLogo

Tags: collision-detection, netlogo

I would like to change the behavior of all turtles when they touch turtles of the other kind. How can I describe this command "when they touch or contact "?

Comment: This is more a specification issue than a programming one (so is off-topic on SO). You need to think more about your problem (and formalize it, perhaps using some math). Once you've got a tentative solution, you might ask a question with an [MCVE] on SO. BTW, StackOverflow is not a *do-my-homework* site (and you'll learn more by thinking by yourself about it)

Answer (score 1):

Tracking whether two objects touch in computer simulations is referred to as collision detection. Look in the NetLogo Models Library (in the File Menu) and open the model called "GasLab Circular Particles", it's an example of collision detection.